# Arithmetic (division) in gawk when forward slash (/) is in the input - perhaps with multiple field separators?

Tags: awk

I have a file with lines similar to the following (unfortunately, this is the *only* format in which another software outputs results):

`1  2  3  5/2  7  17/5  9  10/3  15`

I need to replace it with the following line:

`1  2  3  2.5  7  3.4  9  3.33  15`

In other words, I want GAWK to do the division and replace the fractions (rational quantities)  `5/2, 17/5 and 10/3`  with their decimal values  `2.5, 3.4 and 3.33.`

I tried multiple FS (field separators), but nothing worked.. What's a good way to do this using GAWK?  Thanks.

Would it make it easier if I change the `slash (/)` to a `colon (:)`?

Why do I ask this question?  I was trying to search whether `/` is a substring of `$i`.. (and if the answer is yes, then I would `split()` $i into 2 parts and then do the division).

I read elsewhere that to check whether a field `$i` begins with `F`, they use `if ($i~/^F/)` -- and so I tried `if ($i~///)`, then `if ($i~/"/"/)`, then `if ($i~/\//) (escaping / with a \)` etc.. None of these worked.. So I thought `/` is a special character in Awk.. To avoid special character complications, I thought, let me use `:`.

Comment: FYI ... \ is a backslash - where as / is a forward slash (or just slash) commonly used as a division symbol - check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292580/evaluate-arithmetic-expression-passed-as-argument-in-awk

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`? It's easier with `perl` for instance with things like `perl -pe 's{(\d+)/(\d+)}{sprintf "%.2f", $1/$2}ge'`

Comment: No, doesn't have to be `awk`.. Will look into `perl`.

Comment: Regarding `Would it make it easier if I change the slash (/) to a colon (:)` - so we can help your understanding of awk, what was it you tried or read that made you think that?

Comment: @EdMorton -- I have edited my post and answered your question there (too long to answer within a comment).

Comment: I see. You said you tried `if ($i~/\//)` - that would've worked. `/` is the constant regexp delimiter, when your regexp includes `/`s and you don't feel like escaping them and have nothing else in your regexp that'd cause problems, sometimes it's useful to use a dynamic regexp instead, delimited by `"`.s, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps.

Comment: Oh, okay.. Then probably my `split()` statement would have been wrong!  Will look at the webpage u suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over the fields and split each one on `/`.  If the split generates exactly two substrings, use these to calculate the field's new value:

```bash
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (split($i,a,"/")==2) $i = a[1]/a[2] };1' file
1 2 3 2.5 7 3.4 9 3.33333 15
```

To two decimals, use the `%.2f` format specifier with `sprintf()`:

```bash
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if (split($i,a,"/")==2) $i = sprintf("%.2f",a[1]/a[2]) } };1' file
1 2 3 2.50 7 3.40 9 3.33 15
```

---

Similarly, using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bash
$ mlr --nidx put 'for (k,v in $*) { a=splitnv(v,"/"); if (length(a)==2) { $[k]=a[1]/a[2] } }' file
1  2  3  2.500000  7  3.400000  9  3.333333  15
```

```bash
$ mlr --nidx put 'for (k,v in $*) { a=splitnv(v,"/"); if (length(a)==2) { $[k]=fmtnum(a[1]/a[2],"%.2f") } }' file
1  2  3  2.50  7  3.40  9  3.33  15
```

Note that when using the `nidx` input and output format, the default field delimiter is a single space character.  This means that the input shown in the question has 17 fields, some of which are empty.  These are all replicated in the output, which means the spaces are preserved.

Comment: Beware that as soon as one field is modified,  spacing between field is modified (fields joined with OFS)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas As the specific delimiter used in the input was not specified, I'm also not using a specific delimiter for the output.

Comment: Thanks.. The Awk solution works for me.. Just curious.. What if `nf` is NOT equal to 2 (that is, `nf = 1`)? How is this case handled? And what's the meaning of the `;1` at the end?

Comment: @ShuxueJiaoshou If `nf` is not 2, then the field is left untouched since splitting it on `/` did not generate exactly two strings.  The trailing `1` is a very compact way of writing `{ print }` (which is short for `{ print $0 }`).  It unconditionally outputs the current record.

Comment: It's worth mentioning those awk scripts will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. I used a variable out of habit (I usually go straight into a loop with that variable as the upper bound). As for caring about division by zero, that's a philosophical question, and I lean towards letting the user deal with the consequences of their own input.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier with `perl` (there are also far more systems with `perl` pre-installed than `gawk`, the GNU implementation of `awk`):

```
perl -pe 's{(\d+)/(\d+)}{sprintf "%.2f", $1/$2}ge'
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 's{\d+/\d+}{sprintf "%.2f", eval$&}ge'
```

`s`ubstitutes digits/digits with the result of division formatted with two digits after the `.`.

```
perl -pe 's{(?<!\S)\d+/\d+(?!\S)}{sprintf "%.2f", eval$&}ge'
```

To leave the digits/digits preceded and/or followed by non-white`S`pace (such as `1/0x2`, `A1/2`...) alone.